# symbol resolutions when creating (and linking) libraries

Tags: c++, linker, operating-system, shared-libraries

Suppose `a.cc` defines a function `f_a()` that uses a function `f_b()` defined in `b.cc`. From `a.cc` and `b.cc` I create a dynamic library `libdynamic.so`.

Suppose the file `main.cc` uses `f_a`, I'd compile it as follows:

`g++ -o main main.cc -ldynamic`

How does the dynamic linker bring the definition of `f_a` (and subsequently `f_b`) into the executable? Is the definition of `f_a` in `libdynamic.so` already resolved with `f_b`? Or the dynamic linker will also resolve this (internal) dependency at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a shared library (`*.so`), the definition is *not* brought into the executable.  It remains in the library itself and is resolved at run time, which is why if you remove the shared library the program will not function correctly.

On the other hand, all the internal symbols in the library (in your example, `f_a` and `f_b`) must be resolved when the library is built.  This is evident from the compilation process:

```
g++ -fPIC -c a.cc
g++ -fPIC -c b.cc
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libdynamic.so -o libdynamic.so a.o b.o
```

In the last stage, `g++` calls the linker (`ld`) to link `f_a.o` and `f_b.o`.  In fact, you could (probably) call the linker directly instead:

```
ld -shared -soname=libdynamic.so -o libdynamic.so a.o b.o
```

If you're still curious about the whole process and all its gory details, here is a useful reference article: [*Linkers and Loaders*, by Sandeep Grover](http://linuxjournal.com/article/6463).

Comment: but how is the library resolved at runtime? I mean, f_a is brought into the memory from the library, but f_a() uses f_b(). When does the linker resolve this f_a, f_b dependency?

Comment: Assuming `f_a` and `f_b` are built together into one library, then this dependency was resolved when the library was built.  (Although there will be a relocation later on when the shared library is loaded during run time.)

Comment: so the creation of a shared library involve resolving symbols, which is different from creating static libraries which just concatenate objects together? Just want to clarify.

Comment: Yes, when you create a shared library you need to call `ld` to do the resolutions (at the very last step).  In contrast, creating a static library you just call `ar`, which is primarily an archival utility.

Comment: it seems like symbol resolution when creating .so object is only enforced by passing -Wl,z,defs option. The ld man page says that by default, undefined references in shared library is allowed.

Comment: If you use `nm` to inspect the library, you will see that `f_a` and `f_b` are both present.  Undefined references can occur if your libraries depend on additional libraries not explicitly passed to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Dynamic libraries are linked with the Executable file at Run time(That is when you are running `./main`). The compiler will take care about the solving the dependency at run time. If you want to check the dependency is resolved or not by `nm` command. The default information that the ‘nm’ command provides is-

1. Virtual address of the symbol
2. A character which depicts the symbol type. If the character is in lower case then the symbol is local but if the character is in upper case then the symbol is external
3. Name of the symbol

For more information [nm](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-nm-command/).

After compiling your program just execute `nm exefilename`(i think for your's `nm main`).